# access violation in destroy()

Tags: destructor, destroy, d

I am trying to manage the lifetime from an expensive object using manual memory management and during my unit-tests I seem to crash my program with an access violation in the main method underneath `destroy(bar)` in this example.
This is the minimal example for my problem where I get an access violation.

I don't understand what's going wrong.

```
class Foo { int i;}

struct Bar
{
    Foo _p;
    this(Foo foo)
    {
        _p = foo;
    }

    ~this() {
        import core.stdc.stdlib : free;
        if (_p !is null)
        {
            destroy(_p);
            free(cast(void*)_p);
            _p = null;
        }
    }
}


void main(string[] argv)
{
    import std.conv;
    import core.stdc.stdlib;

    Foo foo = emplace(cast(Foo) malloc(Foo.sizeof));

    Bar bar = Bar(foo);
    destroy(bar);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that destroy sets _p to null "for" you... which means you never actually free it. Do `Foo tmp = _p; destroy(_p); free(cast(void*) tmp);` instead, or something like that, so you keep a temporary copy of the reference beyond the destroy call. That's not what's causing your crash though, that is just a memory leak.

The crash is because, `Foo.sizeof` for a class is the size of the *reference*, not the size of the instance. For classes, you want to `malloc(__traits(classInstanceSize, Foo))`. The documentation mentions this as one of its preconditions: http://dpldocs.info/experimental-docs/std.conv.emplace.3.html

That's causing your crash because you didn't allocate enough space for the vtable (and thus emplace probably corrupted memory too, which eluded type checks due to your cast!). I would malloc and slice it instead of casting it.

```
// malloc the instance size then slice it to get a type-safe representation
void[] memory = malloc(__traits(classInstanceSize, Foo))[0 .. __traits(classInstanceSize, Foo)];
emplace!Foo(memory); // emplace a new one in that memory
```

You also should be careful when passing class references to that struct, since if it wasn't malloced or if there is another reference, you will get a dangling problem.

Comment: You are a hero! Thank you.

Comment: Yeah I ripped this out of some unittest code so I'm not too worried about dangling pointers. The ctor of `Bar` is private and therefore only visible to unittests.